# Report achievement progress by increasing it instead of replacing it

Tags: objective-c, report

I have trouble reporting achievements. I would like to do the following:
When I submit an achivment progress like 1%, I would like to increase the actuall progress not replaccing it.
So if I submit 1% and the user allready have like 4% its have to be 5% not 1%. Is there any way to do this?
Here my actual reporting code:

```
+(void)reportachivementwithidenfitier:(NSString *)identifier percentcompleted:(float)percent{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([defaults boolForKey:@"localplayeravailable"]) {
    GKAchievement *achievement = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: identifier];
    if (achievement)
    {
        achievement.percentComplete = percent;
        achievement.showsCompletionBanner=YES;
        NSArray *achivments=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:achievement,nil];
        [GKAchievement reportAchievements:achivments withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
            if (error!=nil) {
                NSLog(@"Achievement Submission failed with error:%@",[error description]);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Achievement Succesfully reported");
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: achievement.percentComplete += percent ????

Comment: This was my first idea too, however the datas for the actually achievement isn't fetched from the Game Center. The achievement variable doesn't hold any valuables. I know how to fetch data, however it fetch all achievements to an array and i can't select the one for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on this line:

```
achievement.percentComplete = percent;
```

you are setting it to a new value. Simply add the value to it, like so:

```
achievement.percentComplete += percent;
```

Comment: This was my first idea too, however the datas for the actually achievement isn't fetched from the Game Center. The achievement variable doesn't hold any valuables. I know how to fetch data, however it fetch all achievements to an array and i can't select the one for me.

Comment: @user3341586 if you have all the achievements in an array, with the data, how can you not search the array for the object matching the identifier you passed in here: `[[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: identifier]`

Comment: How can i do it? I have an NSArray* achievements Which contains the achievements. And the GKAchievement. How should I Search for the index?

Comment: @user3341586 this is very basic, create a for loop, go through each element, pull out its identifier, compare it to the one you have (used in your question). When you find that one, pull out the percentage and add the new value to it